# Exclude element containing attribute and all its children

Tags: html, dom, xpath

I'm currently trying to retrieve all the elements on a webpage excluding links and their childs.

The page is composed as follow :

```
<body>
    <p>
        ...
        <a href='...'>
            <strong> ... </strong>
        </a>
        ...
    </p>
    <p>
        ...
        <a href='...'>
            <strong> ... </strong>
        </a>
        ...
    </p>
</body>
```

I'm able to get all the elements except links using `//body//*[not(@href)]`.

However I'm also catching children of elements containing `href` attribute.

How to filter-out elements containing the `href` attribute but also its children ?

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, you can specify that you want all nodes that neither have an `href` attribute nor an ancestor with an `href` attribute.

`//body//*[not(@href or ancestor::*/@href)]`